# Python: How to check the value of a non-existent list element without getting IndexError?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm using Python's one-line conditional thus:

```
x = 'foo' if myList[2] is not None else 'bar'
```

to assign to `x` the value of an item at a certain index of a list - **if and only if it exists** - and a different value if it doesn't.

Here's my challenge: `myList` can have up to three elements, but won't always have three. So if the index doesn't exist (i.e. if the index in question is 1+ greater than the size of the list), I'll obviously get an `IndexError list out of range` before the inline conditional can assign the variable:

```
In [145]: myList = [1,2]

In [146]: x = 'foo' if myList[2] is not None else 'bar'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-146-29708b8c471e> in <module>()
----> 1 x = 'foo' if myList[2] is not None else 'bar'

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Checking the length of the list beforehand is not really an option, since I can't know which value I'm interested in is missing (i.e. `myList` can be missing any or all of three possible values. Knowing that it contains only one, or two, or three elements does not help).

**Update:** the reason why I can't assign based on the length of the list is as follows. The list can have a maximum size of 3, and **order is important**. The values populated will be the result of three separate calls to an API. If all calls to the API succeed, I get a full list, and everything is fine. Yet if only two return a value, the list only contains two items, yet **I cannot know which API call has led to the missing item**, so assigning variables is pot luck.

So, long story short: How can I check for a non-existent list item at a certain index, while getting to keep Python's one-line conditional?

Comment: You get an index error not because you cannot assign the value but because the list doesn't have that index.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think testing the length is not an option. Of course it is an option, `IndexError` is only raised if the list is shorter than length 3.

Comment: you say you want "to assign to x the value of an item at a certain index of a list," but that's not what you're trying to do.  you're trying to assign "foo" if the value is not `None` and "bar" otherwise.  i think it would help for you to provide some example values for `myList` and the corresponding desired values for `x`.

Comment: I already know why I cannot assign the value. Therein lies the essence of the problem: trying to check the value of of item that does not exist. So my update above for clafication as to why using the length of the list is not reliable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just test if there are enough elements:

```
x = 'foo' if len(myList) > 2 and myList[2] is not None else 'bar'
```

It doesn't matter if the first 2 elements are missing or if you have more than 3 elements. What matters is that the list is long enough to have a 3rd element in the first place.

Comment: The problem is that if len(myList) is 2, or if len(myList) is 1, I can't know why (i.e. I can't know which value is missing), so assigning variables based on length (and whatever values ARE present) is a shot in the dark.

Comment: @Pyderman: that's an issue with how you construct that list then. Those are issues Python cannot solve; you need to construct your code to avoid placing values at arbitrary indices.

Comment: Values are not being placed at arbitrary indices. In fact, order is important, and the fact that it is so is probably contributing to the issue.

Comment: @Pyderman: but if you are omitting the first value, then everything after that shifts up a spot and you can no longer be sure if `myList[0]` is the first value, or the second value because the first was omitted.

Comment: Yep. The real problem here is that I was placing the values of the three calls to the API into a list, and returning this list in a single getAllTheApiValues()-type function. Then trying to access (and assign based on) elements of this list. I was returning a list in the interest of brevity, but it seems it caused more trouble than it's worth. So I've now made three functions, each returning the appropriate value from the API. More lines of code. Fewer headaches. If you can suggest an even smarter approach, I'm all ears. And thanks for your input.

Comment: @Pyderman: just return `None` for missing values. Using a list (or a tuple, more common) is fine, but just *be consistent* in what you return. Always return 3 elements, just keep the indices stable.

Answer (score 4):

Use try.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

L=[1,2,3]

i=0
while i < 10:
    try:
        print L[i]

    except IndexError as e:
        print e, 'L['+str(i)+']'

    i += 1
```

Output

```
1
2
3
list index out of range L[3]
list index out of range L[4]
list index out of range L[5]
list index out of range L[6]
list index out of range L[7]
list index out of range L[8]
list index out of range L[9]
```

Comment: Good style, programmers should add exception handling. Upvote